# Show that $\mathbb{E}(X_{0}|X_{1},\cdots,X_{n})=c_{0}+c_{1}X_{1}+\cdots+c_{n}X_{n}$ for $(X_{0},\cdots, X_{n})$ Guassian.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am working an exercise as follows:

> Suppose $(X_{0},\cdots, X_{n})$ is a Guassian vector (not necessarily centered). Show that there are constants $c_{0}, c_{1},\cdots, c_{n}$ such that $$\mathbb{E}(X_{0}|X_{1},\cdots,X_{n})=c_{0}+c_{1}X_{1}+\cdots+c_{n}X_{n}.$$

A solution with centered Guassian vector is here: [Conditional Expectation of Gaussian Random Vector of length n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205722/conditional-expectation-of-gaussian-random-vector-of-length-n)

How could I modify the proof if it is not zero mean Guassian vector?

Also, this proof uses density function, but we know that the density function of Guassian vector exists if and only if the covariance matrix is non-degenerate (invertible), right?

**What will happen if the covariance matrix is degenerate?**

Can we still prove the exercise? (This exercise also said that my proof should be valid irrespective of whether the covariance matrix is degenerate or not)...

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the proof in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2209484/215011) to the question you linked. It already assumes a non-centered Gaussian vector. As for the case where the covariance matrix might be degenerate, we can always find a matrix $C$ such that $Z:=X_a- C X_b$
is uncorrelated with $X_b$, so that the equality $$\Sigma_{a,b}=C\,\Sigma_{b,b}\tag1$$ holds; in the general case take $$C:=\Sigma_{a,b}\Sigma_{b,b}{}^+,$$ where $\Sigma_{b,b}{}^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $\Sigma_{b,b}$. (If $\Sigma_{b,b}$ is invertible, then $
\Sigma_{b,b}{}^+$ is the same as $\Sigma_{b,b}^{-1}$.) Continue the proof as before to establish that 
$$E(X_a\mid X_b) = \mu_a + C(X_b - \mu_b),$$
which is equivalent to the result you're trying to show.

---

EDIT: Why does it suffice to take the Moore-Penrose inverse of $\Sigma_{b,b}$? Recall that [every multivariate Gaussian vector is an affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Normal_random_vector) of some vector $Z$ of independent standard Gaussians. We can then write the subvectors $X_a$ and $X_b$ in the form
$X_a = AZ + \mu_a$, $X_b = BZ + \mu_b$, with $A$ and $B$ matrices of constants. Since the covariance matrix of $Z$ is the identity, we calculate $\Sigma_{a,b} = AB^T$ and $\Sigma_{b,b}=BB^T$.

Using properties of Moore-Penrose inverses, we find $\Sigma_{b,b}{}^+=(BB^T)^+=(B^T)^+B^+$ and verify (1):
$$
C\,\Sigma_{b,b}=\Sigma_{a,b}\Sigma_{b,b}{}^+\Sigma_{b,b}
=AB^T(B^T)^+\underbrace{B^+BB^T}_{B^T}
=A\underbrace{B^T(B^T)^+B^T}_{B^T}=AB^T=\Sigma_{a,b}.
$$

Comment: WOW thank you so much. I will read your proof in detail tomorrow. Let me firstly accept your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just finished following your proof. Really a brilliant proof! I didn't know the Moore-Penrose inverse, so thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Thanks. I have updated my answer with additional details.

Comment: WOW. Thank you! Actually I was about to ask you this question. Thank you so much!